# Mac showing Thunderbolt Ethernet as Airport

Tags: macos, wifi, settings

My network interfaces are showing different names to others that I have seen and I believe it may be causing an issue when setting up a virtual box.

Isn't Airport the other name for the Wifi? This shows it as the ethernet port.

Has anyone seen this issue before? I think it may have happened because I installed Android File Transfer or plugged in my Galaxy S4.

[image: Mac network settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure someone isn't playing a joke on you?

Just rename the service. *Click the ⚙ icon...*

[image]

Then rename the server. You can call "Thunderbolt Ethernet" something like "Wi-Fi", "Yo Mama" or anything you wish. You'll also want to change the name of the inactive "Wi-Fi" entry to "Thunderbolt Ethernet". Your software seems to have switched the interface names.

[image]

Comment: This is spot on.  I've seen this happen many, many, times.  You can either rename the interface or remove them and re-add them.